# Unrecognizable Icon. Virus?

Tags: malware, virus

Sorry I'm not sure this would be the best place but I've noticed this icon recently. I'm not sure what it is and it only pops up sometimes. When it does, I can't click it or do anything to it and it disappears a few seconds later. I don't recognize the icon as anything I installed. If anyone recognizes this icon and what program it's for that would be great. I would just like some assurance that its not a virus or some kind of keylogger. Thanks.

[image: picture link]

Comment: Why would a virus or keylogger go out of its way to put an icon in your system tray to advertize that it is there?

Comment: Have you tried clicking it? (Left, Right, double). If one of those opens a window, you can check which program that window belongs to.

Comment: I've tried clicking it and it doesn't do anything. I can't right click to bring up a menu, left clicking doesn't do anything. It comes once then it disappears. I probably wouldn't have cared much or noticed if my current windows opened (like firefox) doesn't keep deselecting if you understand what I'm saying. Like I'm using firefox or some other windows and it's like I click the background deselecting that windows. I never had that till recently and haven't (just happened again here) installed anything that could account for it.

Comment: @Boann I've seen malware install with system try icons. Heck, even evil browser bars are visible.

Answer (score 2):

**Maybe**., **Maybe not**.

Honestly Just an icon is not enough to identify that you have a threat or not. And not any key logger or malware will show itself to the target its presence(unless it was a buggy one).

**Possible explanation for the Mystery Icon:**

- could be an unwanted software that got installed along with any of the softwares you installed.
- could be some types of system operation notifier like a graphic card monitor,etc., (these types of icons somnetimes appears only during some of its operations and then disappears, its no harm)
- could be a malicious software,malware,keylogger,etc.

**Possible ways to detect:**

- Check for any unknown programs installed in your control panel
- Open the toolbar/quicklaunch programs and see if you can find anything suspicious.
- open the windows startup and look for the registered programs (that will be executed at the windows startup)
- Open the task manager and inspect the processes that are running(look for unfamiliar process).

**Solution:**

Once you find the malicious/unwanted program by any of the detection process, try uninstalling it and deleting all the related files from its location(including the temp folder files).

Restart the computer and make sure that the threat is long gone!